# Managing 40 SQL Connections in single desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, settings, sqlconnection

I have a desktop application that we use internally.  The app consists of 5 Databases.  We also have 5 branches with each having there own SQL Server.  We also have Mobile Users who can switch to using there Local SQL Server Express.  We also have a Test Server.

All told that's **25** SQL Connection Strings pointing to the Central(per Branch) SQL Servers, **5** SQL Express Connection Strings for Mobile, then **5** more SQL Express Connection Strings for Mobile TEST, and finally **5** SQL Connection String(*1 per DB*) for the Central TEST Server.  For a GRAND TOTAL of **40** Connection Strings for **1** Application.

What have other's done to wrangle this mess in?  What would you suggest?

I currently store all connections as Connection Strings in my DAL's Settings.settings file.

Comment: I recently asked a very similar question, however after receiving some of the answers it became clear to me I needed to ask a more concise question but to revise the aforementioned question would have rendered some very good answers irrelevant which I thought, unfair.  My previous question is http://stackoverflow.com/q/4088074/46724

Answer (score 1):

I had a program that could switch between n number of databases, and the way that I did it was to have some name for each connection that was a key in a `Dictionary` so it could then find the correct connection string.

I used `DI` (dependency injection) to retrieve the connection strings from `application.xml`.

This way I could easily change the connections strings, add/remove them and when I re-run the program it is updated, but, by going with this approach if the application is running and you changed the connection string the change won't be loaded.

Comment: Hmm, food for thought I guess.  Thanks.  Right now my application switches 'on the fly' from Central to Local if needed...

Comment: I could switch on the fly, but I only loaded the connection strings when the application was loaded, so any changes to the file after weren't going to take effect. For my application this was acceptable, as the connection string is unlikely to change often.

Answer (score 1):

How do you currently handle login? I did one example of this where a login web-service returned the most appropriate connection strings. Obviously this might need some tweaks for the mobile users, but 1 (or maybe 1/branch) service URL may be easier to manage than your cutter scenario, plus you only have to update the centre and all clients see the change.

Of course a central web-service for the data is an option too.

Comment: So, if I read you correctly, I would still have my 10 Mobile Connection Strings to manage but I could 1 login web-service(maybe per branch) to take the place of all the Centrals?  Am I mistaken in that this would require me to have 2 seperate DAL's?  Right now I use 1 DAL (Linq2SQL) for data access in all environments.

Comment: @Refracted - I don't see how getting the connection strings via a service affects the need for a different DAL

Comment: Sorry I was referring to your last statement, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Refracted - yes, that perhaps *would*.